# what is a fully type-inferred language? and limitations of such language?

Tags: types, programming-languages, functional-programming, type-inference, type-systems

As far as I know,any programming language which doesn't require to write type annotations in the source while writing a function or module and if that chunk of code is "type-correct" , compiler will infer the types and compiles the code. is there more to it?

is(are) there a such language(s)? if yes are there any limitations on it's type system?

Update 1:
Just to be **really** clear , I am asking about a statically typed,fully type-inferred programming language not a dynamically typed programming language.

Comment: Python and Perl come to mind. They are not compiled languages, but that's hardly relevant. There are situations where type inference doesn't DWIM -- in my experience Python is a bit too paranoid, and Perl a bit too relaxed.

Comment: python and perl are dynamically typed programming languages ,types are bound to values/vars at *run-time*,where as i am asking about language where types are established at compile-time *statically typed,fully type-inferred* language

Comment: Did you try reading http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_inference ? Also What does fully-type inferred mean?

Comment: @Euphoric Fully type inferred means that there's no expression whose type can't be determined without a type annotation.

Comment: @GuyCoder Actually it kinda doesn't , in GHC i guess some variation of this langauge is used as intermediate language,simonPJ talks about it a lot.

Comment: here is the link http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/Charles/YOW-2011-Simon-Peyton-Jones-Closer-to-Nirvana

Comment: Take a look at ACL2. It may look like dynamically typed, but it allows to reason about all the type properties of the code. Of course, at a price of not being fully Turing-complete.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The limitation of full type inference is that it doesn't work with many advanced type system features. As an example consider Haskell and OCaml. Both of these languages are *almost* fully type inferred, but have some features that can interfere with type inference.

---

In Haskell it's type classes combined with polymorphic return types:

```
readAndPrint str = print (read "asd")
```

Here `read` is a function of type `Read a => String -> a`, which means "for any type `a` that supports the type class `Read` the function `read` can take a `String` and return an `a`. So if `f` is a method that takes an int, I can write `f (read "123")` and it will convert "123" to the Int 123 and call `f` with it. It knows that it should convert the string to an Int because `f` takes an Int. If f took a list of ints, it would try to convert the string to a list of Ints instead. No problem.

But for the `readAndPrint` function above that approach does not work. The problem here is that `print` can take an argument of any type that can be printed (that is any type that supports the `Show` typeclass). So there's no way for the compiler to know whether you want to convert the string to an int, or a list of ints, or anything else that can be printed. So in cases like this you need to add type annotations.

---

In OCaml the problematic feature is polymorphic functions in classes: If you define a function that takes an object as its argument and calls a method on that object, the compiler will infer a monomorphic type for that method. For example:

```
let f obj = obj#meth 23 + obj#meth 42
```

Here the compiler will infer that `obj` must be an instance of a class that has a method named `meth` of type `int -> int`, i.e. a method that takes an Int and returns an Int. You can now define a bunch of classes that have such a method and pass instances of that class as arguments to `f`. No problem.

The problem occurs if you define a class with a method of type `'a. 'a -> int`, i.e. a method that can take an argument of any type and return an int. You can not pass an object of that class as an argument to `f` because it doesn't match the inferred type. If you want `f` to take such an object as its argument, the only way is to add a type annotation to `f`.

---

So those were examples of languages that are almost fully type inferred and of cases where they're not. If you'd remove the problematic features from those languages, they'd be fully type inferred.

Consequently basic dialects of ML without such advanced features are fully type inferred. For instance I assume that Caml Light is fully type inferred since it's basically OCaml without classes (however I don't actually know the language, so that's just an assumption).

Comment: An excellent answer,which actually explains why full-type inference is difficult and hence not totally desirable.

Answer (score 19):

**What is type inference?**

Historically, type inference (or type reconstruction) meant that *all* types in a program can be derived without requiring essentially *any* explicit type annotation. However, in recent years, it has become en vogue in the programming language mainstream to label even the most trivial forms of bottom-up type deduction as "type inference" (e.g., the new `auto` declarations of C++11). So people have started adding "full" to refer to the "real" thing.

**What is *full* type inference?**

There is a broad spectrum to what degree a language can infer types, and in practice, almost no language supports "full" type inference in the strictest sense (core ML is about the only example). But the main distinguishing factor is whether types can be derived for bindings that do not have a "definition" attached to them — in particular, parameters of functions. If you can write, say,

```
f(x) = x + 1
```

and the type system figures out that f e.g. has type Int → Int, then it makes sense to call this type inference. Moreover, we talk about *polymorphic* type inference when, e.g.,

```
g(x) = x
```

is assigned the generic type ∀(t) t → t automatically.

Type inference was invented in the context of the simply-typed lambda calculus, and polymorphic type inference (aka Hindley/Milner type inference, invented in the 1970s) is the claim to fame of the ML family of languages (Standard ML, OCaml, and arguably Haskell).

**What are the limits of full type inference?**

Core ML has the luxury of "full" polymorphic type inference. But it hinges on certain limitations of polymorphism in its type system. In particular, only definitions can be generic, not function arguments. That is,

```
id(x) = x;
id(5);
id(True)
```

works fine, because `id` can be given polymorphic type when the definition is known. But

```
f(id) = (id(5); id(True))
```

does not type check in ML, because `id` cannot be polymorphic as a function argument. In other words, the type system does allow polymorphic types like ∀(t) t → t, but not so-called higher-rank polymorphic types like (∀(t) t → t) → Bool, where polymorphic values are used in a first-class manner (which, just to be clear, even very few explicitly typed languages allow).

The polymorphic lambda calculus (also called "System F"), which is explicitly typed, allows the latter. But it is a standard result in type theory that type reconstruction for full System F is undecidable. Hindley/Milner hits a sweet spot of a slightly less expressive type system for which type reconstruction still is decidable.

There are more advanced type system features that also make full type reconstruction undecidable. And there are others that keep it decidable but still make it infeasible, e.g. the presence of ad-hoc overloading or subtyping, because that leads to combinatorial explosion.

Answer (score 2):

Another limitation are higher ranked types. 
For example, the following program does *not* typecheck in languages with ML style type inference:

```
foo = let bar f = (f ['a', 'b', 'c'], f [1,2,3]) in bar reverse
```

The type checker can assign to f the type [Char] -> [Char] or [Int] -> [Int], but not forall a.[a]->[a].
In ML, Ocaml and F# there is no way to fix this, as you cannot even write higher rank types.

But Haskell (via a GHC extension) and Frege support higher rank types. But because only higher rank type checking (as opposed to higher rank type inference) is possible, the programmer is required to give a type annotation, though, for example:

```
foo = let bar (f :: forall a.[a]->[a]) = (f ['a', 'b', 'c'], f [1,2,3]) in bar reverse
```